# Code for linear gradient in Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, colors, linear-gradients

```
#woodwhite{position:absolute;left:1000px;width:345px;height:1400;top:0px;z-index:10;
background:-webkit-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));
background:-o-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));
background:-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));
background:linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,1));"}
```

These gradient codes which I got from w3 aren't working for all the browsers. 
Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ create your own

Answer (score 1):

```
background: #999; /* for non-css3 browsers */

filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000'); /* for IE */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000)); /* for webkit browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ccc,  #000); /* for firefox 3.6+ */
```